# How much free disk space is needed for compaction?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

According to this article: http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/03/16/compaction-nuance.html

> "It looks at the the total space used by all sstables, adds it up, and
>   checks it against available disk space"

Does it mean that total space is counted for all sstables stored on given node, or for all sstables that will be compacted?

We can assume that we have SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.

Comment: Its impossible to know the size the compacted sstable will be until it occurs, since theres no way of telling the amount of shadowed data in tombstones or overwritten cells. Its probably best to assume worst case and its the size of the 2 files added together.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the source code in CompactionTask#buildCompactionCandidatesForAvailableDiskSpace for Cassandra 2.1.20](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/f7431b432875e334170ccdb19934d05545d2cebd/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/compaction/CompactionTask.java#L379) the write size is for all sstables that will be compacted (sstables that are not expired).

Also, as a general recommendation, you should fill up your disk up to 50% of the disk size so compactions can be executed safely.

Comment: So assuming that there will be no parallel compactions, we can say that needed free disk space is no more than the size of the biggest keyspace, right?

Comment: The CompactionTask is taking into account only the sstables for that compaction, not for all compactions that can be run in parallel. As I said before, the safest would be to fill up your disk up to 50% of their capacity. Beyond that, you might end up in trouble. I've seen systems that were filling up the space pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

For SizeTieredCompactionStrategy compaction strategy at least 50% disk space of total disk space of Cassandra data file should be free so that compaction can be executed safely.